# Expected number of times a result comes up: Proof of formula

Tags: probability

If I am flipping a fair coin, and want to know the expected number of heads after $n$ flips, then I immediately know the answer is $\frac{n}{2}$. Similarly, with a fair die, the number of $5$'s that come up after $n$ rolls is on average $\frac{n}{6}$. Presumbably, the general form of this rule is as follows:

$$
\text{Expected number of times a result comes up}=P(\text{result}) \times\text{Number of trials}
$$

This is *much* less labour intensive than working out the weighted average in another way. To compute the average number of $5$'s that come up after $n$ rolls, I could work out:

$$
\left(P(\text{Zero $5$'s coming up}) \times0\right)+\left(P(\text{One $5$ coming up}) \times1\right)+\left(P(\text{Two $5$'s coming up}) \times2\right)+...+\left(P(\text{$n$ $5$'s coming up}) \times n\right)
$$

Is it possible to use this second, more labour intensive result, to prove the first?

Comment: Do you know how to find the sum of an Aritmetic-Geometric series(AGP)?

Comment: Fastest way to see the claim is, I think, to use [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/#:~:text=Linearity%20of%20expectation%20is%20the,weighted%20average%20of%20possible%20outcomes.), just choosing an indicator variable for each trial.  Or, for that matter, just a simple induction.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Unfortnunately not. I do, however, know how to find the sum of an arithmetic series and a geometric series. If an AGP isn't too much of a step up, then I'd be happy to research these if they are needed to answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's definitely possible. The number of 5s in $n$ rolls of a dice will follow a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $1/6$. This means that for $k \leq n$, 
$$
\mathbb{P}(X = k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k},
$$
where $p = 1/6$. So then you can look at
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X) &= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} k.
\end{align}
Write out the binomial coefficient
$$
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}
$$
and then take out a factor of $np$ to get:
\begin{align}
&n p\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-k}.
\end{align}
Now we will re-write the sum over an index $j = k-1$. So when $k=1$, we get $j=0$. And when $k=n$, we get $j=n-1$ (after all there are only $n$ terms in the sum however we write it). So we get
\begin{align}
& n p\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{j}p^{j}(1-p)^{n-1 -j}  \\
&= n p\bigl(p + (1-p)\bigr)^{n-1}  \\
&= np.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for responding. I don't quite understand your answer. So when you used $j$ instead of $k$ in your proof, presumably $j$=$k-1$, right? Also, could you please justify going from the second line to the third line (I don't know why the top number on the sigma symbol changes from $n$ to $n-1$).

Comment: OK I tried to add some more detail. We shift 1...n down to 0...n-1: There are $n$ terms in the sum no matter how we write it. Try plugging in $k=n$. You should get the same thing as when you plug in $j=n-1$ on the next line.

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes complete sense now! Earlier, I asked a new question about an explanation of this proof, so I am sorry if I was wasting your time. But what you wrote definitely does reinforce what others have written.